# Why does it take so long to drop a constraint?

Tags: sql-server-2012, primary-key, database-performance

SQL Server 2012 SP3

It's a primary key backed by a clustered index.  If it matters, there are 62M rows in the table, with 24GB of data, 6.5GB of indexes (there are 3 in total).

(EDIT: the statement eventually fails, saying that `dbo.SORT temporary run storage` has filled PRIMARY (and thus the disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping the clustered index (doesn't have to be PK) turns the table into a heap and rebuilds all non-clustered indexes because the row locator has changed from the clustered index key to a RID.

You can avoid the overhead of rebuilding the non-clustered twice by fist dropping the non-clustered indexes so they are untouched when the table becomes a heap. Then recreate the new clustered primary key followed by non-clustered indexes.

An alternative to dropping and recreating the non-clustered indexes is to disable them (ALTER INDEX...DISABLE) before dropping the clustered index. When the new clustered index is subsequently created, the disabled non-clustered indexes are automatically enabled (rebuilt). The benefit of this disable method is disabled index meta-data is leveraged, which avoids cluttering the script with non-clustered index create DDL.

I'll add that tables should generally have a clustered index, primary key or not. The implication is you need to have free space of roughly 120% of the table size to support a recreate/rebuild the clustered index.

Comment: "*rebuilds all non-clustered indexes because the row locator has changed from the clustered key to a RID*"  That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Hello, I suppose SQL server will also rebuild the table into a heap after dropping a primary key constraint. My question is: how to maintain the balance between cost and benefit of modifying indexes? It seems like the more data I have, the greater the cost for modifying or creating new index. However, queries change all the time and it is necessary to modify indexes. How do you cope with it?

Comment: @AndesLam, you are right the cost of creating new indexes or modifying existing ones is proportional to table size. This can be done online depending on the SQL server edition. One can also use `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)` to modify an existing index in many scenarios, which avoids the sort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I am dropping and inserting new primary keys? I find this so complicated all of a sudden. IIRC, the re-organization of table is inevitable. However, the cost for switching NCI leaf node pointers from clustered key to RID then again to clustered key is kinda unnecessary. Is it possible to cut the latter cost?

Comment: @AndesLam, do you mean dropping and creating the clustered primary key? If you disable/drop the non-clustered indexes first, those are not touched (rebuilt). I updated my answer for clarity. Hopefully that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

A table of this size is going to be difficult to drop a constraint on. There are various workarounds, such as

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/dropping-large-clustered-primary-key-fills-up-tempdb

If you drop a primary constraint the system will re-organize the data on disk. That is expensive from a resourcing standpoint.

Comment: That link is about filling up tempdb.  My question is about filling up PRIMARY.

Comment: Hi Ron, you are correct about the reference to tempdb. In this case the solution is the same for you, regardless of the tempdb reference. Generally some sort of export, drop and re-create process will be your workaround.